# Subscript out of range using Split in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have found this VBScript that displays the name of the default printer in HTA app. It works fine as long as there is a default printer set, but when I run it on a new user load (when there is absolutely nothing set as default printer) it gives an error:

> Subscript out of range: '[number:0]'

Is there any way to fix this?

```
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
dim defaultprn

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


defaultprn = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device")

arrPrnStr = Split(defaultprn,",")
fullPrinterString = arrPrnStr(0)


arrFullPrnStr = Split(fullPrinterString,"\")

shortPrinterName= arrFullPrnStr(Ubound(arrFullPrnStr))

document.write("Default printer: " + shortPrinterName)

If shortPrinterName="Fax" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Microsoft XPS Document Writer" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2013" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Microsoft Print to PDF" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Microsoft XPS Document Write" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Microsoft Document Image Writer" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Microsoft Office Document Image Writer" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2005" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2006" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2007" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2008" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2009" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2010" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2011" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2012" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2013" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2014" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2015" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2016" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2017" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2018" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2019" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2020" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2021" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2022" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2023" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2024" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2025" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="OneNote" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName=Empty  Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName=Null  Then
changedefaultprinter()

End If
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message points to this line - arrPrnStr = Split(defaultprn,",")

Comment: No, that error points to this line - `fullPrinterString = arrPrnStr(0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to create an array with an empty variable. Since the user had no default printer the registry read came back blank. Putting that blank into an array produced your error. So you just check its not empty e.g. using <>.
I added an extra IF statement to check before it does the rest of the code. Also there is an else at the bottom, which means if it was emtpy then Output a custom message for no default printer.

```
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
dim defaultprn    
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
defaultprn = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device")    

if defaultprn <> "" Then

arrPrnStr = Split(defaultprn,",")
fullPrinterString = arrPrnStr(0)  
arrFullPrnStr = Split(fullPrinterString,"\")
shortPrinterName= arrFullPrnStr(Ubound(arrFullPrnStr))
document.write("Default printer: " + shortPrinterName)
If shortPrinterName="Fax" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Microsoft XPS Document Writer" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2013" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Microsoft Print to PDF" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Microsoft XPS Document Write" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Microsoft Document Image Writer" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Microsoft Office Document Image Writer" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2005" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2006" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2007" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2008" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2009" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2010" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2011" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2012" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2013" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2014" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2015" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2016" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2017" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2018" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2019" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2020" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2021" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2022" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2023" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2024" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="Send To OneNote 2025" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName="OneNote" Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName=Empty  Then
changedefaultprinter()
ElseIf shortPrinterName=Null  Then
changedefaultprinter()

Else
document.write("Default printer: " + "None")
changedefaultprinter()
End if

End If
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to trigger function changedefaultprinter() if the default printer is not set?
P.S. This code did manage to fix error popup, but it won't trigger function changedefaultprinter(), if it could do that as well that would be perfect.

Comment: In other words, I want to trigger changedefaultprinter() function when there is no defaultprn or when shortPrinterName is equal to Fax, Send One Note, etc.

Comment: yep you can. If you look at the bottom after it says Else, anything in there will be run if there is no default printer. Just put changedefaultprinter() before or after the document.write. I've just updated my answer for you. Please mark as answered if this fixes your problem.

Comment: One small problem is still there, changedefaultprinter() gets triggered even if there is default printer, I have set my cannon LBP 6020 as default and it still triggered changedefaultprinter(). Is there a way to resolve this? For example if printer is anything else except listed variables in the script and except no default printer not to trigger changedefaultprinter()

Comment: hmm not sure. you could try removing these two:
    ElseIf shortPrinterName=Empty  Then
    changedefaultprinter()
    ElseIf shortPrinterName=Null  Then
    changedefaultprinter()

Comment: what does the output say if your cannon is default? E.g. Default printer: " "